# Rendering a partial inside a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails. I have this block in my view afrikaans.html.erb

```
<% @afrikaans.each  do |course| %>
  <div class="course">
    <h3 class="course-name"><%= link_to course.name, course.url  %></h3>
    <% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
    <p class="course-description_en"><%= course.description_en %></p>
    <% else %>
    <p class="course-description_se"><%= course.description_se %></p>
    <% end %>  

    <% if course.youtube_url.blank? == false %>
      <p><%= raw ApplicationHelper.youtube_embed(course.youtube_url) %></p>
    <% end %>     
    <% if course.language_id == 1 %>
    <p>&nbsp; <%=  image_tag("eng.png", :alt => "England", :class =>"round") %></p>
    <% else %>
    <p>&nbsp; <%= image_tag("swe.png", :alt => "Sweden", :class =>"round") %></p>
    <% end %>

    <% if ApplicationHelper.active_link?(course.url) == false %>
      <td><%= I18n.t('home.broken_link') %></td>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= course.nbr_of_votes %> <%= I18n.t('home.votes') %></p>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I also have another file swahili.html.erb with the same structure. I wanted to implement something like this

afrikaans.html.erb

```
<% @afrikaans.each do |course| %>
 <%= render 'shared/partial' %>
<% end %>
```

So that I can also have

swahili.html.erb

```
<% @swahili.each do |course| %>
 <%= render 'shared/partial' %>
<% end %>
```

The partial will contain the part of the block. I've tried this but it's not working. My question is this even possible in rails and if so what could be the problem. What options do I have if it isn't possible so that I can avoid the repetition since the two files have the same structure?

**Update**. This One worked out for me. I only needed to add `:course => course` on the block so that my views becomes something like

```
<% @afrikaans.each  do |course| %>
  <%= render 'shared/course_body', :course => course %>
<% end %>
```

Of course I've not named my partial "partial". This was just a matter of asking. Thanks to one @Alexander Panasyuk's answer.

Comment: its possible. whats the error you get with your code?

Comment: First thing to check is the partial file: `_partial.html.erb`, i.e. the file name.

Comment: It is very well possible. What does it mean "not working"? Are you geting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create *shared* directory within your *app/views* path. And create file **_partial.html.erb** inside *shared*:

```
 <div class="course">
    <h3 class="course-name"><%= link_to course.name, course.url  %></h3>
    <% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
    <p class="course-description_en"><%= course.description_en %></p>
    <% else %>
    <p class="course-description_se"><%= course.description_se %></p>
    <% end %>  
    <% if course.youtube_url.blank? == false %>
      <p><%= raw ApplicationHelper.youtube_embed(course.youtube_url) %></p>
    <% end %>     
    <% if course.language_id == 1 %>
    <p>&nbsp; <%=  image_tag("eng.png", :alt => "England", :class =>"round") %></p>
    <% else %>
    <p>&nbsp; <%= image_tag("swe.png", :alt => "Sweden", :class =>"round") %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if ApplicationHelper.active_link?(course.url) == false %>
      <td><%= I18n.t('home.broken_link') %></td>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= course.nbr_of_votes %> <%= I18n.t('home.votes') %></p>
  </tr>
```

Then render your partial in **afrikaans.html.erb** like that:

```
<% @afrikaans.each do |course| %>
  <%= render 'shared/partial', :course => course %>
<% end %>
```

or in **swahili.html.erb**:

```
<% @swahili.each do |course| %>
  <%= render 'shared/partial', :course => course %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most definitely possible, and usually a good idea.

In the future it would be nice if you could post the actual results and/or error messages you get, which would help a lot when trying to help you.

That said, I'm guessing you need to pass the `course` variable to your partial. Change

```
<%= render 'shared/partial' %>
```

to

```
<%= render 'shared/partial', :course => course %>
```

Partials do not have access to local variables in other partials. In that sense you can think of each partial as separate methods on the same object instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render 'shared/partial', locale: 'swahili', course: course %>
```

You will have local vars 'locale' and 'course' in your partial set to 'swahili' and @course, respectively. Also, I'd advise to name your partials something more meaningful, like 'course'.